# How to convert Rows to Columns in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've a table `Columns`

[image]

and a second table `Response` in which all data is saved.

[image]

Now I want to create a SQL View in which the result should be like this

[image]

I tried using pivot

```
select UserId ,FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment
from
(
  select R.UserId ,R.Text , C.ColumnName
  from [Columns] C
  INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId
) d
pivot
(
  max(Text)
  for ColumnName in (FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment)
) piv;
```

but that didn't worked for me, I also referred this [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server) but was not able to implement it. Any ideas how to achieve the same in SQL View?

**Scripts for Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Columns](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Columns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into [Columns] values('FromDate',1)
insert into [Columns] values('ToDate',1)
insert into [Columns] values('Project',1)
insert into [Columns] values('Comment',1)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Response](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [ColumnId] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Response] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
insert into [Response] values(1,1,'1/1/2012',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,2,'1/2/2012',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,3,'p1',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,4,'c1',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,1,'1/1/2013',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,2,'1/2/2013',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,3,'p2',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,4,'c2',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,1,'1/1/2014',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,2,'1/2/2014',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,3,'p3',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,4,'c3',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,1,'1/1/2015',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,2,'1/2/2015',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,3,'p4',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,4,'c4',1)
```

Comment: Show what didn't work for you.

Comment: Can you show the pivot query you tried to use?

Comment: @WEI_DBA : shared

Comment: what happens when a userid is on multiple projects?

Comment: @DForck42 : Like I mentioned the desired output in my question, each record for the corresponding `UserId` should come without duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if the column types aren't going to change, or you only need a subset of them, you could just filter them out and then join on them rather than write a pivot.  I wrote it using a cte, but they could just as easily be sub-queries:

```
;with fd as
(
    select
        UserID,
        [Text] as FromDate,
        row_number() over (partition by userID order by ID) as DEDUP
    from response
    where ColumnID = 1
),
td as
(
    select
        UserID,
        [Text] as ToDate,
        row_number() over (partition by userID order by ID) as DEDUP
    from response
    where ColumnID = 2
),
p as
(
    select
        UserID,
        [Text] as Project,
        row_number() over (partition by userID order by ID) as DEDUP
    from response
    where ColumnID = 3
),
c as
(
    select
        UserID,
        [Text] as Comment,
        row_number() over (partition by userID order by ID) as DEDUP
    from response
    where ColumnID = 4
)
select
    fd.*,
    td.ToDate,
    p.Project,
    c.Comment
from fd
    inner join td
        on fd.UserId = td.UserId
            and fd.DEDUP = td.DEDUP
    inner join p
        on fd.UserId = p.UserId
            and fd.DEDUP = p.DEDUP
    inner join c
        on fd.UserId = c.UserId
            and fd.DEDUP = c.DEDUP
```

Comment: your query returns duplicate records, is there any way to get unique records.

Comment: @SidM I fixed my typo. let me know if this works correctly now

Comment: No, its still giving the duplicate results

Comment: @SidM ok, I think I've fixed it

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I worked on your answer.

```
select UserId ,FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment
from
(
  select R.UserId ,R.RText , C.ColumnName
  from [Columns] C
  INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId
) d
pivot
(
  Min(Rtext)
  for ColumnName in (FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment)
) piv

UNION
select UserId ,FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment
from
(
  select R.UserId ,R.RText , C.ColumnName
  from [Columns] C
  INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId
) d
pivot
(
  Max(Rtext)
  for ColumnName in (FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment)
) piv;
```

Comment: `max` and `min` functions returns null for date type values, here for columns `FromDate` and `Todate`. Also you are considering only two rows for the UserId=2, there can be more rows for any UserId

Comment: True. I was going based on your data.

Answer (score -1):

You can query like this

```
;with cte as 
(
    select r.*, 
    c.name 
    from Response r 
        inner join Columns c
            on r.columnid = c.id
) 
select 
    Userid, 
    max([FromDate]) as [FromDate],
    max([ToDate]) as [ToDate],
    max([Project]) as [Project],
    max([Comment]) as [Comment] 
from cte
pivot
(
    max(Text) for name in ([FromDate], [ToDate], [Project], [Comment])
) p
group by userid
```

Comment: 2 problems in the answer, `1` : `max` function returns null for `date` type values, here for columns `FromDate` and `Todate`. `2` :  only 1 row returned for `UserId=2`

Comment: Provide your input sample data as scripts

Comment: shared the scripts

Comment: Updated answer based on your input scripts. It is working fine for me..

Comment: I don't get the result for project `p2`, did you really run the query you mentioned in your answer or just edited and posted it here.

P.S. I didn't downvote your answer.